# Trying to use variables from variable file in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Hello I am having a hard time using variables from a variable file in my playbook. I am using a variable file snapshot that is on the same This is my code I am just trying to loop through one item in the list I have.

snapshotvar.yml

```
kvm1
  - vm1
  - vm2
kvm2
  - vm4
  - vm3
  - vm5
```

kvmsnapshot.yml

```
---
- hosts: kvm2
  vars_files:
    - snapshot.yml
  tasks:
  - name: Create kvm snapshot
    ovirt_snapshot:
      vm_name: "{{ item }}"
      description: prepatch
    loop: "{{ kvm2[2] }}"
```

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

you have some error in your var file: (you forget :) and give the correct name (snapshot.yml)

```
kvm1:
  - vm1
  - vm2
kvm2:
  - vm4
  - vm3
  - vm5
```

after if you  just want to use the item with second index, no need to loop:

```
---
- hosts: kvm2
  vars_files:
    - snapshot.yml
  tasks:
  - name: Create kvm snapshot
    ovirt_snapshot:
      vm_name: "{{ kvm2[2] }}"
      description: prepatch
```

if you want to loop over all values of kvm2:

```
---
- hosts: kvm2
  vars_files:
    - snapshot.yml
  tasks:
  - name: Create kvm snapshot
    ovirt_snapshot:
      vm_name: "{{ item }}"
      description: prepatch
    loop: "{{ kvm2 }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of syntax errors.

1. Fix YAML of the file snapshotvar.yml

```yaml
shell> cat snapshotvar.yml 
kvm1:
  - vm1
  - vm2
kvm2:
  - vm4
  - vm3
  - vm5
```

2. Fix the name of the file *snapshotvar.yml* and the name of the variable *kvm2* that you want to iterate

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - snapshotvar.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ kvm2 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  item: vm4
  item: vm3
  item: vm5
```

Fit the task to your needs.